# Prove that X is measurable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

I encountered the following question.

''Let *X*:($\Omega$,$\mathcal{A}$)$\rightarrow$($\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}$) be a random variable. Let $\mathcal{F}$ = {$A:A=X^{-1}(B), B \in \mathcal{B}$ }=$X^{-1}$($\mathcal{B}$).

Show that $X$ is measurable as a function from ($\Omega$,$\mathcal{F}$) to ($\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}$).''

My attempt: By definition it suffices to show that $X^{-1}$($\mathcal{B}$)$\subset \mathcal{F}$. However from the question it is evident that this holds. I can't imagine that this it is so simple. What is the point I am missing?

Comment: By definition a measurable function maps one measurable space on another measurable space. Therefore the solution I have in mind is showing that $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ is indeed a measurable space. In other words, I will show that $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 1):

You are not missing anything. By definition of Random variable and measurable function it follows easily.

In fact, $X^{-1}(B)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra w.r.t which $X$ is measurable.